# how to auto fill the power-form fields in docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I am doing the docusign integration with my application.

I have a powerform in my demo account which is opened every time a user request to sign a contract. When the user opened the powerform there are about 12 fields he have to fill. except the email field which is autofill by the docusign.

Now i want the functionality that if a user opened that powerform he already have the options which he filled during the signup process.

Like `first name` `last name` `phone no`. Can i do this from api? i have searched the api but did not succeeded.

**P.S :** right now i am opening the form by the powerform url. It redirects the user to that powerform to open and fill it. Email is automatically being filled but not the name and other fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot mix Powerform and API, API cannot fill document triggered from Powerform. It better to use API if you want to do proper integration with DocuSign. But if you want to do integration with Powerform then you can send the values of the DS label added in your document by doing below:

If you DS Servertemplate has multiple text tabs like, PhoneNumber, Salary etc then using HTTP GET, you can populate tab value like below:

```
{PowerformUrl}&PhoneNumber={PhoneNumberValue}&Salary={SalaryValue}&activateonly=1
```

where PhoneNumberValue and SalaryValue are the values which you want to prepopulate in the document. Also if you have an HTML form for the customer to collect these values then call DS Powerform URL with signer's email and name along with the doc label values like below:

```
{PowerformUrl}&PhoneNumber={PhoneNumberValue}&Salary={SalaryValue}&SignerRole_UserName={SignerName}&SignerRole_Email={SignerEmail}&activateonly=1
```

SignerRole will the role which you added in the DS Server Template, on which you have created a Powerform.

Doing this way Powerform will automatically be triggerd from your HTML Form/Application, and intermediatery page where signer needs to add all Signer's email and name will be skipped.

More details on implementation is available [here](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-populate-custom-document-fields-in-a-web-powerform)

Comment: sorry for late replying!. actually i have a powerform already placed in the demo account by the client. Till now which i have learned is he made this powerform fields by pixels i think, how can `{PowerformUrl}&PhoneNumber={PhoneNumberValue}&Salary={SalaryValue}&activateonly=1` automatically populate the fields in my powerform also my powerform is in the form of pdf.

Comment: moreover, right now i am opening the form by the powerform url. It redirects the user to that powerform to open and fill it. Email is automatically being filled but not the name and other fields.

Comment: i want to ask what is the use of activateonly?

Comment: When the flag is active (=1), an email is sent to the first recipient with a link that initiates the signing session without requiring the signer to enter an emailed access code, which is the case when the flag is not enabled. It is important to note that using this flag still provides the same level of signer authentication without the burden of entering an access code from an email, since in either case the signer still has to access their email to initiate signing.

The activate only flag is not applicable to Direct PowerForms, since emails are not sent to initiate a signing session.

Comment: I have also updated my answer with a link which covers all the topic as explained in my answer also