# Embedded signers from my application shouldn’t need to login

Tags: docusignapi

I basically have my embedded signing process working, including the Authorization Code Grant process.

My issue is the following: When users of my application are directed to the embedded signing url, to sign documents in the envelope just created in the backgroud calling the relevant API (https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/features/embedding) they need to log in.

In another question I read that embedded signers should never need to log into docusign.

Additional info: I am using a sandbox account, with one account. This is also the AccountId from which I am calling the rest API to create the envelope for the user that is should be redirected to said envelope.

How can I make it so that signers do not need to log in?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! PLEASE upvote all useful answers (including those to others' questions). And PLEASE check/accept the best answer to your own questions.

Answer (score 0):

It is up to you, the app developer, to determine if signers should log in to DocuSign. In your use case, you don't need the signers to have DocuSign credentials.

There are two remaining issues:

### Authenticating who the signer is

You will want some level of authentication of the signer's identity. Otherwise the signature will have no legal force since it will be easy both to forge a signature (Susan pretending that she is Frank) and to repudiate a signature (Susan signed, but now claims that she didn't. How do you prove that she did, in fact, sign.)

If your application makes users (who will become signers) login to the app, that is a form of authentication. You can also turn on authentication options from DocuSign. Eg include KBA (Knowledge Based Authentication) in the signing request.

Or if you have an employee who is operating the app, the employee can check the signers' identity before allowing the signer to sign via your app.

### Getting the Signing Ceremony without requiring a login

There are a couple of ways to do this depending on the envelope features and document contents you want signed.

Easiest is to use a powerform.

Or your app can create the envelope, get the URL for the signing ceremony, then redirect the user to the signing ceremony.

You can have a system account login (eg "HR department) to obtain an access token / refresh token that will be used to create the envelopes. Or for a corp IT project, JWT Grant might be better.

Please also see my [related SO answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54781040/64904) Please update your question if you have further questions on this same subject.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! So as I have multiple documents employees need to sign, and I want to upload them from pdf files, I am using your second solution. I am using a system account login and am obtaining an access token. When directing a user in my app to docusign through this method, the user still needs to log in. I think I am missing some setting somehow.

So if I understand correctly, my implementation (create envelope, get URL) should not result in required login, but It seems this is happening anyway. Still a bit confused

Comment: Are you setting the clientUserId parameter when you create the recipient object? You're using the [EnvelopeViews::createRecipient](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient) to get the url for the signing ceremony? (And redirecting to the URL in 2 minutes or less from when you receive it?) Do you have the account level setting Account / Security settings page / Login Requirements setting to not require recipient login?

Comment: Thanks for your answers, now I know all the options to get it working.

Comment: So a small follow up on my question. I figured out what was going wrong. It in fact had nothing to do with the embedded signing in this case. It was a problem in the Authorization Code Grant Process. ( https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-code-grant ) In my application this happens in an automated process straight before the embedded signer is sent to Docusign to sign documents. In requesting an authorization code, Docusign requires an active login session. I think I will have to change around this process to make it work.