# How do you create DocuSign Signers from my app users?

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I'm trying to choose the appropriate authentication flow for my application. I have a portal that users create accounts/login to. When they login for the first time, I want to present them with a "Terms & Conditions" form that requires a valid signature. I want to save the signed form in our database (and link to it from our Admin panel).

I don't necessarily want users to have to create a DocuSign account to sign with. In this previous question: [Embedded signers from my application shouldn’t need to login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54810351/embedded-signers-from-my-application-shouldn-t-need-to-login/54823971#54823971) @larry-k says:

> If your application makes users (who will become signers) login to the app, that is a form of authentication. You can also turn on authentication options from DocuSign. Eg include KBA (Knowledge Based Authentication) in the signing request.

Here he alludes to making my App Users into Signers, but I'm not sure how this works. I don't want to use Knowledge Based Authentication, I'm more envisioning a SSO process to create a DocuSign User based on the App User information of the user logging in.

The [same article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54810351/embedded-signers-from-my-application-shouldn-t-need-to-login/54823971#54823971) suggests PowerForm as a possible solution. What happens after the user signs the form? How can I obtain the signed copies? I gather you cannot mix/match PowerForms with API integrations? I don't want to have to require an admin to login to DocuSign to collect signed forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: What happens after the user signs the form?

A: just like any other envelope signed with Docusign, it is stored in the DocuSign cloud for the account that created the PowerForm.

A: How can I obtain the signed copies?

Q: You can download them using the eSignature REST API. You can either do this periodically (polling, not recommend) or get webhook notifications using Connect and get the signed PDF this way.

Q: I gather you cannot mix/match PowerForms with API integrations?

A: You can do that! You can have a PowerForm and you can also have separate API integration that downloads the PowerForm signed docs into your website.

Comment: This is good information, thank you! But, back to this issue of identity - PowerForms are an "anonymous" solution. What's the next step up from that? Users would have to have a DocuSign account? Is there any way to automate the DocuSign user registration process?

Comment: PowerForms are not anonymous, they just don't require you know AHEAD OF TIME who the user is. They still have to provide their information (Email+name)
You can have various means of authentication for signers, like SMS. 
https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-implementing-docusign-recipient-authentication

Comment: PowerForms seems like the right fit. As far as authentication goes, JWT seems like the best option for a service that connect to get signed PDFs?

Comment: agreed, JWT would work pretty well for you.